# How to customize the encoding of a text file in c++?

Tags: c++, encoding, character-encoding, binaryfiles, huffman-code

I am working on huffman file compression project. Till now I know it works something like:

```
file.txt(original) -> file.huf(encoded, compressed) -> file.txt(decoded)
```

What I have to do is to open the txt file, generate the huffman code, but how can I replace those code in the binary code file of the original file. For example, if `file.txt` stores `abc` then its ASCII encoded file will store `01100001 01100010 01100011` and huffman-coded file i.e `file.huf` should store `10 11 0` and then this file should be decoded using the encoding map generated.

My question is to how can I do this in C++ at the file  implementation level, how can I alter the binary file?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out, in simple words, make the code for an alphabet and then for another and combine, iterate this till the code is equal to or more than 8 characters containing 1 and 0, then this sequence of 8 digits is encoded to some character and stored in a file.
This way file can be compressed.